# Click link to send email...use GET?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, post, get

I have an HTML table containing data with a link beside each. When the link is clicked, an email should be sent, and the email should correspond to the record in the row in which the link was clicked.

So, I click the link, the browser should go to /some_controller/:id/resend_email.

My question is: should I GET or POST to this URL? I understand that sending an email is a POST type action, but how can I accomplish this when a link is clicked?

FWIW, I'm using Rails 3.

Note: I am constrained to not using Javascript for this.

Answer (score 0):

You should `POST` if parameters are being sent with the request, otherwise use `GET`.

```
<%= link_to "Resend E-mail", :controller => 'some_controller', :action => 'resend_email', :id => your_id_here, :method => :post %>
```

`link_to` with explicit `:method => :post` requires javascript, though.

The alternative is using a form to POST with a submit button instead.

For more information, you should read this article: [Methods GET and POST in HTML Forms](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/methods.html).

Comment: But how can I accomplish this when a link is clicked?

Comment: Adam, using :method => :post does use Javascript. If I turn off Javascript in my browser's settings, the link performs a GET request when clicked, and I get a routing error as my route only accepts POST. Not using Javascript was a requirement.

Comment: I would just set it up to use GET, then, honestly, or create a form and use a submit button to POST.